# Intellij Projects thinks it's using gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have this maven project that i'm implementing.

Usually, my projects builds with maven and there is a relaod icon from maven that pops up when I make changes inside my `pom.xml`.

Recently, I imported a gradle project and It made changes to my intellij configs.

Now, instead of the maven reload icon I get this one from gradle : [image: Gradle reload icon]

Here is a full project screenshot

[image: Full project]

Comment: Try re-importing the project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Delete .idea directory from the project first. Update to the current release version: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: I use modules from micro-services, I do not have any .idea for this project

Comment: `.idea` directory is always created inside the project root on the initial import.

Comment: I changed the screenshot to a full project screenshot, I do not see my `.idea`

Comment: Might be in another location, use your file manager to find it.

Comment: I disable the `gradle` plugin and the maven icon now appears, I will also try to find the `.idea` and delete it